# Access function inside filesystemwatcher event function powershell

Tags: function, powershell, scope, global-variables

I want access a  function inside filesystemwatcher created event function.  I tried using a global function but i never see output on console.

```
#Script Parameters
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, position=1)]
    [String]$path
)

#Global Function
function global:myFunction (){
    Write-Host "myFunction"
}

#FileSystemWatcher properties
$fsw = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher 
$fsw.Path = $path
$fsw.Filter = ""
$fsw.IncludeSubDirectories = $True  
$fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = $True

#Created event function
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $fsw -EventName Created -Action{  
  $global:myFunction #trying to access global function
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only problem is a **syntax confusion** about how to invoke a global function:

```
$global:myFunction # WRONG - looks for *variable*
```

looks for a *variable* named `myFunction` in the global scope.

**Omit the `$` to call the *function*:**

```
global:myFunction # OK - calls function
```

That said, given that all scopes in a given session by default see global definitions, **you don't need the `global:` scope specifier - simply invoke `myFunction`**:

- The only time you need `global:` explicitly is if there's a *different* `myFunction` definition in the current scope or in an ancestral scope, and you want to explicitly target the global definition.
  Without `global:`, such a different definition would *shadow* (hide) the global definition.

To put it all together:

```
# Script Parameters
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, position=1)]
    [String]$path
)

# Global Function
function global:myFunction {
  param($FullName)
  Write-Host "File created: $FullName" 
}

# FileSystemWatcher properties
$fsw = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher 
$fsw.Path = $path
$fsw.Filter = ""
$fsw.IncludeSubDirectories = $True  
$fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = $True

# Created-event function
$eventJob = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $fsw -EventName Created -Action {  
  myFunction $EventArgs.FullPath  # Call the global function.
}
```

Note that I've extended the code to pass the full filename of the newly created file to `myFunction`, via the automatic `$EventArgs` variable.

---

**Alternatives**:

**Modifying the global scope from a script can be problematic** due to the potential for name collisions, not least because global definitions linger even after the script terminates.

Therefore, consider:

- either: moving the code of function `myFunction` directly into the `-Action` script block.
- or: calling a (possibly temporary) script *file* from the `-Action` script block.

Also note that event action blocks typically write output to the success output stream, not directly to the host with `Write-Host` - if they need to produce output at all - where it can be collected on demand via the `Receive-Job` cmdlet.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify explicitly your function inside Action scriptblock. Like so

```
#FileSystemWatcher properties
$fsw = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher 
$fsw.Path = $path
$fsw.Filter = ""
$fsw.IncludeSubDirectories = $True  
$fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = $True

#Created event function
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $fsw -EventName Created -Action {  
    #Describe your function here
    function global:myFunction (){
        Write-Host "myFunction"
    }
    #There call your function
    global:myFunction
}
```